# Can't UPDATE all column values only few columns are getting updated

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update all column values, as you can see from the code. But only the first three columns get updated and last two values get updated.

1. Home_number
2. Office_number
3. Fax_number

does not get updated.

Please help solve the following problem.

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"]) && $_POST["submit"] !="")
{
    $usersCount = count($_POST["F_name"]);
    echo "$userCount";

    for ($i = 0; $i < $usersCount; $i++) 
    {
        mysql_query("UPDATE contactss set F_name='" .                                     
$_POST["F_name"][$i] . "', L_name='" . $_POST["L_name"][$i] . "', mob_number='" . $_POST["mob_number"][$i] . "', Home_number='" . $_POST["Home_number"][$i] . "', Office_number='" . $_POST["Office_number"][$i] . "', Fax_number='" . $_POST["Fax_number"][$i] . "', email='" . $_POST["email"][$i] . "', Address='" . $_POST["Address"][$i] . "' WHERE C_id='" . $_POST["C_id"][$i] . "'");
    }
    header("Location:list_user.php");
}
```

Comment: make sure the field name in the html form that is sending this is correct, try to echo the query somewhere and look at it as a query see if the field values are empty or not

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the values properly check the field names

Comment: and don't use mysql driver, use pdo or mysqli instead